# Three fingers not detected and auto drag only using Touchégg

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, touchpad

I got [Touchégg](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg) working for my touchpad using [`evdev`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev) but now I am having two issues. I am using Ubuntu 12.10 with GNOME 3.6.

1. Moving the cursor is automatically seen as a drag, which means it auto selects text etc. instead of moving only the cursor. Why is this?
2. Three fingers are never detected by touchegg. For example when I want to do a three finger tap it recognizes it only as a two finger tap, why is this?

   ```
   xinput list-props 11 | grep Capabilities
   ```

   Results in `Synaptics Capabilities (316):    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1` which means that it has three finger support [as explained here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Using_xinput_to_determine_touchpad_capabilities.).
3. What I like to have is to do a three finger drag (any direction) to act as the super key, which means gnome shows all windows. Is this also possible without Touchégg/evdev?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run these commands:

```
synclient TapButton2=0
synclient TapButton3=0
synclient ClickFinger2=0
synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0
```

And afterward, see if you have the same problem with 3 fingers? What driver are you using?

Comment: I am trying to get touchegg to work using evdev, so I believe those commands do not work as a I am getting `Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`.

Comment: Btw I am using the default Ubuntu synaptics drivers.

Comment: It's recomended to use synaptics driver from Ubuntu 11.04:
https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/ConfigureDevices

The same problem with this driver?